# Facebook Api to post use submitted image to a specific page

Tags: javascript, facebook, cordova, facebook-graph-api

Here is what I am trying to achieve - I want to take input from my users as some text and image and post it to a page created by me. The user using the mobile app , does not have any any access to that facebook page. I want to post to that page anonymously on behalf of the user. The page is created by me so I should have access to it. I am really confused what to look for. I have set up an app in facebook developer from the same account who is the creator of the page and I can login user's and have their access token.By the way, if it's relevant I am building a hybrid app and using cordova facebook native plugin

Comment: see my answer. btw, it is not a good idea to let other people post anonymously to your page. you never know what they post, and you are responsible for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the API call you need, there are code examples for several languages: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed#publish

Take a look at the code for the JavaScript SDK, just use that API endpoint with the correct parameters in your cordova plugin.

You need to use a Page Token with the `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permissions. More information about Tokens:

- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/